# Ckeditor not Storing as i formatted into mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor basic version 4.3. When i am storing data in MySQL the formatted data doesn't get stored. For example when I use bullet points or numberings it's not  getting stored as I format. How to resolve this problem?

This is the code I used to integrate and store.

```
<script src="ckeditor1/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

   <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea> 

   <script>
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
   </script>

<?php
    $abt_description =$_POST['editor1'];    
    $insert_news = mysql_query("insert into table (colum) values ('$abt_description');
?>
```

Comment: add sample source code and sample saved result in database, try stripslashes($_POST['editor1']);

Comment: no i ve tried it already no use

Answer (score 2):

As the commenter says, `stripslashes()` solves the problem. Add before the insert:

```
$abt_description = stripslashes($abt_description);
```

Note: I recommend using `mysql_real_escape_string()` on your input.

Comment: i am not able to store bullets or numbers as i format in ckeditor.

Comment: How are you getting the content back from the DB? Lists work for me just fine (both <ol> and <ul>) with version 3.6.2

Comment: list work  for me to but the bullets or numbers is not getting stored

Comment: Check your CSS, maybe they are removed... Search for something like this: `list-style-type: none;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $insert_news = mysql_query("insert into table (colum) values ('".$abt_description."');
```

Comment: And You need to stored with symbol of bullets and numbering or just html format only ?...

Comment: if i am formating bold its getting stored but if i format with number or bullets its not getting stored

Answer (score 0):

You need the [HTML Writer Plugin](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_output_format) to have a pretty, formatted output in CKEditor. It's not available in basic build to save bytes and keep things as simple as possible. Use the [on-line builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder), select *Basic* preset and add *Html Output Writer* plugin manually to your package.

Of course, you can just download standard/full package which contains *HTML Writer Plugin* by default.